# Trouble with global dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
#messagebox is not imported automatically w/ tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox as tkMessageBox
from tkinter import ttk
from random import random as rand


class Square(object):
    """ class to use for each square """
    def __init__(self):
        self.mine_yn = False
        self.flag_yn = False
        self.prox_num = 0   # number of nearby mines, parse_mines() will fill this in.
        self.button = None  # ttk.Button instance.


def parse_mines():
    """Look at how many mines are next to a given square,
    store in each Square instance that is inside of sqr_dict. """
    global sqr_dict
    global mine_frame
    print('in parse_mines, sqr_dict='+str(sqr_dict))

    def try_a_square(sq): #sq = coordinate string(key)
        try:
            if sqr_dict[sq].mine_yn == True:  return 1
            if sqr_dict[sq].mine_yn == False: return 0
        except KeyError:
            print('KeyError for '+sq)
            return 0

    n = 0
    for x in range(5):
        for y in range(4):
            #check the 8 adjacent squares.
            n = n + try_a_square('x'+str(x+1)+'y'+str(y+1))
            n = n + try_a_square('x'+str(x+1)+'y'+str(y  ))
            n = n + try_a_square('x'+str(x+1)+'y'+str(y-1))
            n = n + try_a_square('x'+str(x  )+'y'+str(y+1))
            n = n + try_a_square('x'+str(x  )+'y'+str(y-1))
            n = n + try_a_square('x'+str(x-1)+'y'+str(y+1))
            n = n + try_a_square('x'+str(x-1)+'y'+str(y  ))
            n = n + try_a_square('x'+str(x-1)+'y'+str(y-1))
            if sqr_dict[('x'+str(x)+'y'+str(y))].mine_yn == False:
                (sqr_dict[('x'+str(x)+'y'+str(y))]).prox_num = n

            print('x'+str(x)+'y'+str(y)+': '+str(n)) #(debug) print n for each sq
            #sqr_dict[('x'+str(x)+'y'+str(y))].button.text=(str(n)) #(debug) show n on each button.
            n = 0



def create_mine_field():
    global mine_frame
    global sqr_dict

    sqr_dict = {}

    mine_frame = tk.Toplevel(root)
    mine_frame.grid()

    #what to do if user hit 'X' to close window.
    mine_frame.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", mine_frame_close)


    # create grid of squares (buttons)
    for x in range(5):
        for y in range(4):
            coord = 'x'+str(x) + 'y'+str(y)
            sqr_dict[coord] = Square()
            #print('coord='+coord) #debug
            #populate with mines
            if ( rand()*100 < mines_pct ):
                sqr_dict[coord].mine_yn = True
                print(str(sqr_dict[coord].mine_yn))
            else:
                sqr_dict[coord].mine_yn = False 


            if sqr_dict[coord].mine_yn:  
                t = '*'
            else: t = ' '
            # draw boxes
            sqr_dict[coord].button = ttk.Button(mine_frame, text=t, width=3 )
            sqr_dict[coord].button.grid(column=x, row=y)
            # done, next: parse!
            print('in create_mines, sqr_dict='+str(sqr_dict))

            #parse_mines()



def root_close():
    root.destroy()

def mine_frame_close():
    root.destroy()


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("MineSweeper")

mines_pct = 20
start_button = ttk.Button(root,text="Start",command=create_mine_field)
start_button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I'm trying to make a simple minesweeper game with tkinter. If I run the above code a simple mine field appears. However if I uncomment the call to parser() then nothing shows up and it seems like it never finds any mines in the sqr_dict dictionary. (parser() will fill in the numbers of adjacent mines for each square)

I don't understand why this function would cause trouble before it is even called. No mine field appears when it's called. Please kindly give me your suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: _"However if I uncomment the call to parser() "_ -- I see no call to `parser()` nor any definition for something called `parser`. Did you mean to write `parse_mines()`?

Comment: Sorry, yes that is what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason nothing shows up is because you are using both `pack` and `grid` on widgets that are children of the root window. Within any given window you must only use one or the other.

Comment: I changed the start_button.pack() to start_button.grid(). Everything is using grid now, but with parse_mines() uncommented I still get nothing.

Comment: @JayTaffer: when I run your code I get `KeyError: 'x0y1'. And are you realy sure that calling `parse_mines` inside a loop inside another loop  is really the right thing to do?

Comment: Excuse my noobishness. Yes, I did not mean to have parse_mines() inside the loop. Thank you again! Everything seems to work now.